# ERROR #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a table in a database with SQL but a 1064 error appears. Can you help me solve my problem.

```
CREATE TABLE keys (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`key` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`level` int(2) NOT NULL,
`ignore_limits` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`is_private_key` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ip_addresses` text,
`date_created` int(11) NOT NULL
 )
```

Comment: Your table name is a reserved word in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`key` and `keys` are  keywords in mysql. You can solve the problem by changing them.

```
CREATE TABLE mykeys (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `key_value` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    `level` int(2) NOT NULL,
    `ignore_limits` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `is_private_key` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ip_addresses` text,
    `date_created` int(11) NOT NULL
)
```